# How can I set the password of the root user from the salt master to the minion?

Tags: salt-stack

I need to set the password of the root user of ubuntu so that all the minions have the same password and the users can not modify it, how can I do that from the salt master?

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to set the password:

`salt 'minion_id' shadow.set_password root 'PASSWORD_HASH'`

If you don't have a password yet, you can use this command to create one:

`salt 'minion_id' shadow.gen_password 'PLAIN_PASSWORD'`